# A car dealer filed an 8300 form with the IRS after I made a large cash down payment on a car. Do I need to do anything about it?

Tags: united-states, car, cash

I made a $10,000 cash down payment for car I bought 2 weeks ago. The dealer send me copy of form 8300 they filled for that transaction.

What happened next?

*Mod Note: [Form 8300](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8300.pdf) is a form to "Report.. Cash Payments over $10,000 Received in A Trade or Business" to the IRS.

Answer (score 8):

https://www.communitytax.com/tax-form/form-8300/

> Form 8300 is a document that must be filed with the IRS when an individual or business receives a cash payment over $10,000.

The dealership received that much cash from you, so they filed the form with the IRS.  It's to prevent money laundering.

If you're not a criminal with lots of cash on hand from your illegal earnings, then you have nothing to worry about.